# No file base when copying a file in solution explorer

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visual-studio-2019, visualsvn, windows-10-desktop

It used to be, that one could copy a file in solution explorer, and when looking at the changes in the commit window, it compared to the file it was copied from by default.
This worked flawlessly and was very useful.

For a while now, this hasnt been working anymore. When copying an item in solution explorer like I used to, it will just show as a new file without a base to compare it to.
I'm not sure whether the problem lies with the VisualSVN-plugin we use or maybe TortoiseSVN itself. Maybe even the VS update to 2019..

Did anybody have this issue?

Doing a quick google only brought me to "repair move" which is not what I want since I don't delete the files i copy from usually.

I would assume its not a re#er problem..

EDIT: I only copy within the same project using ctrl-c/ctrl-v in solutionexplorer.

We use VisualSVN 7.1.2 along with Re#er Ultimate 2019.1.2. We also have the productivity power tools installed, but those are all the plugins we use.

EDIT2: I tried it on a third persons machine yielding the same results:

[image: screenshot of merge tool having trouble to find a base]

Comment: i will need to discuss your request with the development team because the problem does not reproduce on my side. Do you maybe have any other extensions installed? Note that I can say that we did not receive similar reports about VisualSVN 7.x and Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: i adjusted the question. thats strange.. its the same on my coworkers machine. tortoise is up to date btw

Comment: We can reproduce this behavior. Thank you! I will update the answer as soon as I have more information.

Comment: Any news yet? Its almost been a month

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem yet? Its been quite a while..

Comment: I've contacted the development team and it appears that the problem is still under investigation.

Comment: Any news on this? Its been over 6 months, this is a small problem and we pay for this product...

Answer (score 1):

This could be a bug and your report needs additional investigation. Consider the following suggestions:

- Anything new in the logs when you make a copy? The logs are in **%TEMP%\VisualSVN**.
- How do you make a copy? What command do you run? Is it copy-paste? Do you copy within one project?
- What project templates do you use in Visual Studio?

Note that you can update your question with this information and/or contact support@visualsvn.com. A couple of screenshots would be great, too. We will help.

Comment: Thanks!
The logs dont show any entries about copied files..
For our projects only the VS-builtin templates were used, my UI-projeccts where i copy the files around (using ctrl-c, ctrl-v) are WPF apps. I only ever copy within the same project.

Comment: i wrote them multiple times; they werent able to fix that bug in over a year. So i changed to another solution since im not paying for unsupported buggy software.